# Integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x^2+1} dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How to evaluate :

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x^2+1} dx$$

The integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is quite easy, but how could we integrate this function from $0$ to $\infty$?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla the integral on $(0,\infty)$ seems to be simplier, however.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, the integral on $(-\infty,\infty)$ you mean? Yes, is triviallly zero by symmetry.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla no, I wrote what I meant. Your link shows only the indefinite integral and the properties of $\frac{\sin x}{x^2+1}$, the `integrate` part is discarded. A correct query (in one of several notations tha wolframalpha understands) should be `Integrate[Sin[x]/(x^2+1),{x,0,Infty}]`

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, you are rigth, silly me!

Comment: There is no solution in terms of elementary functions; Mathematica returns a result in terms of the exponential integral or hyperbolic integral. Is it of any help if I post this?

Comment: integrals are not solved, solve means something else not related to integrals.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that $x^2+1=(x-i)(x+i)$, we can rewrite the integral as $\displaystyle\frac1{2i}\bigg(\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x-i}dx$ $-\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x+i}\bigg)$, and then express each of these in terms of [trigonometric integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral), by rewriting $\sin x$ as $\sin\Big((x\pm i)\mp i\Big)$, and then employing the [angle addition formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) for $\sin(a\pm b)$. Unlike

the related integral $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos x}{x^2+1}dx=\frac\pi{2e}$ , this one does not seem to possess a closed form which

does not involve special functions.